# How can I build a histogram in 3D?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, histogram

I have list of lists. Example:

```
A = Range[Range[N], 1]; where N = const.
```

Then I fill lists.

That's mean the Length@A[[k]] are different; where k<=N.

How can I build Histogram3D with this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean you're pre-binning the data, so you have a (ragged) array of heights:

```
heights = {{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
```

Fill out the array into a rectangular form with something like:

```
heights = PadRight[#, 5] & /@ heights
```

Figure out what you bin boundaries are in each dimension (lengths will be one more than the number of bins):

```
x = Range[1,6,1]
y = Range[1,11,2]
```

Give the heights as a constant function:

```
Histogram3D[{{0, 0}}, {{x}, {y}}, heights &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(The data in the first argument is fake since it's not actually used for anything.)

Comment: I'm formulate my question not quite correctly, but your answer help me to find decision. thanks

Comment: +1 I feel really sad when someone solves a problem and the OP does not bother to vote up.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, probably you want a BarChart (I may be wrong)

```
a = Table[i, {i, #}] & /@ Range[10]

BarChart3D[a, ChartLayout -> "Grid"]
```

[image]

**Edit**

If you *really* are looking for a 3D histogram:

```
a = Flatten[
  Table[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[i, .3], {10 i, 2}], {i, #}] & /@ Range[10], 1]  

Histogram3D@a
```

[image]

Comment: @Brett If that feels silly, imagine MY feelings when I did the same :D